# Java String Regex Matching Syntax

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please explain why this won't work in Java but appears to in every other tool I have tested it on.  The type of strings expected are similar to `:a004871-5553:z05072-990`

The expected outcome is to match the `a0` at the beginning of the line.

```
String[] parts = nextLine[0].split(":");
String part1 = parts[1]; 
if (part1.matches("a[0-9]"))....
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
if (part1.matches("a[0-9]"))
```

Because `String#matches` matches the full input not just part of input

This should work though:

```
if (part1.matches("a[0-9-]+")) {...}
```

Comment: Many thanks that fixed it.  I am sorry about the ":"  I had edited the question but not before you answered.

Comment: Oh no issues, I edited my answer based on your edited question :)

Comment: Anubhava, a further clarification if I may.  What does the hyphen '-' after the numeral signify?

Comment: That is to match hyphen character which is present in your input.